# Jpgraph : how set label for group bar column chart in php

Tags: php, jpgraph

here is  my jpgraph demo code:

```
<?php // content="text/plain; charset=utf-8"
// $Id: groupbarex1.php,v 1.2 2002/07/11 23:27:28 aditus Exp $
require_once ('jpgraph/jpgraph.php');
require_once ('jpgraph/jpgraph_bar.php');

$datay1=array(35,160,0,0,0,0);
$datay2=array(35,190,190,190,190,190);
$datay3=array(20,70,70,140,230,260);

$graph = new Graph(450,200,'auto');    
$graph->SetScale("textlin");
$graph->SetShadow();
$graph->img->SetMargin(40,30,40,40);
$graph->xaxis->SetTickLabels($gDateLocale->GetShortMonth());

$graph->xaxis->title->Set('Year 2002');
$graph->xaxis->title->SetFont(FF_FONT1,FS_BOLD);

$graph->title->Set('Group bar plot');
$graph->title->SetFont(FF_FONT1,FS_BOLD);

$bplot1 = new BarPlot($datay1);
$bplot2 = new BarPlot($datay2);
$bplot3 = new BarPlot($datay3);

$bplot1->SetFillColor("orange");
$bplot2->SetFillColor("brown");
$bplot3->SetFillColor("darkgreen");

$gbarplot = new GroupBarPlot(array($bplot1,$bplot2,$bplot3));
$gbarplot->SetWidth(0.6);
$graph->Add($gbarplot);

$graph->Stroke();
?>
```

this code has no error and this is working perfectly...my problem is how can I set labels for this multi bars for identifying ...

How can I set A LABELS..

Comment: I USED THIS CODE BUT IT doesn't work for me....$graph->SetLegends(array('Pass','Fail','Not Eligble'));
$graph->Add($p1);

Comment: can anyone help us to dvelop this code????

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Hs4hR.png i want to apply this img to above graph...I think that's the best solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$graph->legend->SetPos(0.5,0.98,'center','bottom');
$bplot1->SetLegend("Pass");
$bplot2->SetLegend("---");
$bplot3->SetLegend("---");

$gbarplot = new GroupBarPlot(array($bplot1,$bplot2,$bplot3));
$gbarplot->SetWidth(0.6);
$graph->Add($gbarplot);

$graph->Stroke();
```

Write this line in your code. For more info please see this url:

[Class Reference](http://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/classref/Legend.html)

[With Example](http://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/chunkhtml/ch14s04.html)