# how can I add labels for accumulated bars at the x-axis in jpgraph

Tags: php, jpgraph

How can I add labels for my accumulated bars in jpGraph?
I can add two accumulated bar plots which consist of several bar plots.
At the x-axis there are labels for the year of the data shown.

[image]

Is it possible to add a label above or below (in example image red and blue arrows) the accumulated graphs?

In the legend there would be the names of the data entries (like percentage of whatever is green, percentage of whatever 2 is blue ...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jpgraph : how set label for group bar column chart in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004932/jpgraph-how-set-label-for-group-bar-column-chart-in-php)

Comment: I don't agree, the other post is about setting the legend information for each datarow. I want to set the label for each accumulated bar (stack).

Comment: Yes you are right i think this example might be helpful `Example 14.3. Adjusting the interval for the labels` -  https://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/chunkhtml/example_src/manual_textscale_ex3.html

Comment: Yes i see... In that case perhaps you could work something out with `SetLabelFormatString` https://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/classref/AxisPrototype.html#_AXISPROTOTYPE_SETLABELFORMATSTRING so that you could produce labels such as `group1(2015),group2(2015),..` etc. Or check out this example https://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/chunkhtml/example_src/accbarframeex02.html the graph is seen here https://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/chunkhtml/ch15s02.html. Try adding a different border color for each group and then add the appropriate legends for each group. Hope this is more helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Based on [`jpGraph Example 14.3`](https://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/chunkhtml/ch14s08.html) you could try to set the labels manually.

The `PHP` code of `Example 14.3` is:

```
require_once ('jpgraph/jpgraph.php');
require_once ('jpgraph/jpgraph_bar.php');

// Some data
for($i=0; $i < 12; ++$i) {
    $databary[$i] = rand(1,20);
}
$months=$gDateLocale->GetShortMonth();

// New graph with a drop shadow
$graph = new Graph(300,200);
$graph->SetShadow();

// Use a "text" X-scale
$graph->SetScale('textlin');

// Specify X-labels
$graph->xaxis->SetTickLabels($months);
$graph->xaxis->SetTextLabelInterval(2);

// Set title and subtitle
$graph->title->Set('Textscale with tickinterval=2');

// Use built in font
$graph->title->SetFont(FF_FONT1,FS_BOLD);

// Create the bar plot
$b1 = new BarPlot($databary);
$b1->SetLegend('Temperature');

// The order the plots are added determines who's ontop
$graph->Add($b1);

// Finally output the  image
$graph->Stroke();
```

### `Example 14.3`

[image]

On the above example if you check the `$months` variable you will notice that it is an array of short month names `["Jan","Feb","Mar",...,"Dec"]` returned by Function `GetShortMonth()` used in [`jpGraph DateLocale Class`](https://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/classref/DateLocale.html). What you could do is manually create an array of the desired labels in your graph, or populate an array of the desired labels per each accumulated bar stack (depends on your code). The `PHP` code of `Example 14.3` indicates that functions `SetTickLabels()` and `SetTextLabelInterval()` are the ones used to set and properly position the `x-Axis` labels.

```
// Specify X-labels
$graph->xaxis->SetTickLabels($months);
$graph->xaxis->SetTextLabelInterval(2);
```

Comment: Thank you. But the Problem is that the tick label in my example is the year (2015 and 2016) and I need additional labels for the accumulated bars.